# MVC Routes - limiting direct browsing to action methods

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

I was wondering how I could stop users from accessing an action method directly through browsing to the url. I have a ViewUser action method in which an ID is passed from the url. Right now the user can substitute the ID with a different one and the action method will execute. Right now I don't have a specified route set up. Is it possible to only allow access to the action method from ActionLinks only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For obvious reasons there is no way to restrict access to a url from specific `<a />` tags. You should instead use something like [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) and check if the currently authenticated user has the rights to do what he/she requests.

Answer (score 1):

Use UUID instead of id. UUID.randomUUID().
If that is not an option, think about passing in an authentication token.